# Trouble CPU Mining with CGMiner and CPUMiner on Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: miner-configuration, mining-profitability, linux, cpu-mining

I just started mining within the past week on my laptop but I am trying to set up 2 dedicated mining servers to run 24/7. I've been using UfaSoft's CPUMiner on Windows 8 on the laptop, but I cant seam to get it to work on either of my servers.

I am running a Dell Dimension 433c with a 600 MHz Pentium Pro with 256 MG RAM & a Dell Dimension L1000R with a Pentium III again with 256 MB RAM both with Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS x86 installed.

I downloaded the source code for both UfaSofts CPU Miner and CGMiner directly from the developer's website, downloaded all the dependencies needed for a rig without any GPUs and did a #make install for both.

With UfaSoft I keep getting Error 80072550 when ever I try to mine.
With CGMiner, It won't initialise and says that all devices are disabled. A friend of mine told me that it was picking up a GPU and was then disabling the CPU miner as a response but I think he may not know what he's talking about.

Any help that I can get would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It's pointless. With that kind of hardware, it would take you on the order of a month to mine a dollar's worth of Bitcoins, and the electricity used would cost you many times that.

Comment: is mining at all relevant anymore?

Comment: Mining is completely relevant, the blockchain/mining mechanism is perhaps the MOST interesting thing about Bitcoin - It's just that a lot of us despise these CPU mining questions because most of them are actually asking "how do I mine on a botnet" or "how do I mine on my company's equipment without their knowledge/consent."